# How to install Cygserver

Tags: linux, cygwin, window, cygwin-x

I'm programming in UNIX, so I'm using Cygwin. But functions of IPC does not work on it, just in Cygserver. How can I install it? I'm looked in google and did not find any concrete information.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Which IPC library are you using?

Comment: I don't know, I just installed the cygwin with all the devel and linus packages

Comment: I sorry but your question is very vague, and incomplete.  Cygwin is a compatibility layer for Windows, namely so you can use fork() calls.  IPC is a very general term.  Have you written code on Linux/Unix and are trying to port it over to Windows?  What is working where and what is not?  IPC stands for Inter-Process Communication--it is a generic term, and you need to provide much more detail.  Some code, and some of the actual errors would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for my question, I will elaborate more. I need to use function like semaphores, shared memory management in UNIX, and I would like to do it in the Windows with cygwin (because installing Ubuntu with Windows 8 is very difficult). But Cygwin does not support these type of function, only cygserver. The problem is that I don't know what is Cygserver, and I didn't found any precise information on the Cygwin site.

Comment: Well, you probably want to start here:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/mindex.html
Semaphores are in here:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/contents.html
From what I found, cygserver uses XSI IPC.  
Perhaps you might find running a virtual machine of Ubuntu easier.  Otherwise, this is well beyond me.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Cygserver is actually part of the base `cygwin` package that every Cygwin user has installed.

Proof:

```
$ cygcheck -f /usr/sbin/cygserver
cygwin-1.7.35-1

$ cygcheck -f /usr/bin/cygserver-config
cygwin-1.7.35-1
```

So you already have it installed, but you need to configure it:

1. Launch "Cygwin Terminal" "as Administrator"
2. $ cygserver-config

Output:

```
$ cygserver-config
Generating /etc/cygserver.conf file


Warning: The following function requires administrator privileges!

Do you want to install cygserver as service?
(Say "no" if it's already installed as service) (yes/no) yes

The service has been installed under LocalSystem account.
To start it, call `net start cygserver' or `cygrunsrv -S cygserver'.

Further configuration options are available by editing the configuration
file /etc/cygserver.conf.  Please read the inline information in that
file carefully. The best option for the start is to just leave it alone.

Basic Cygserver configuration finished. Have fun!
```

Note that in addition to the `To start it` instructions:

1. It will automatically start at boot
2. You can start and stop it (or disable it) under [`services.msc`](http://www.herongyang.com/Windows/Service-Control-Panel-Services-Console.html)

Answer (score 1):

Usage and installation of `cygserver` is fully explained in [its own page](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygserver.html) of the Cygwin User Guide.

Answer (score -2):

[step1: check "cygrunsrv.exe" on your system under c:\cygwin\bin?
step2 : if not see "cygrunsrv.exe" on system under c:\cygwin\bin
select package 'sygrunsrv:NT/W2K service initiator'  and install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM7tQ.png)

Comment: Nope, `cygrunsrv` is [something completely different](http://web.mit.edu/cygwin/cygwin_v1.3.2/usr/doc/Cygwin/cygrunsrv.README). It's not even a service (like Cygserver), it's just a tool to create and manipulate with Windows services.